# Enable minor mode given org-mode tag

Tags: org-mode, minor-mode

Is it possible to set a minor mode only when viewing org-mode files with a certain tag? If so, how could I achieve this?

Comment: When you say the file has a certain tag, do you mean it contains at least one headline with a particular tag, or that the tag was specified with [`#FILETAGS:`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-Inheritance.html)?

Comment: Also, it doesn’t precisely answer your question, but you can manage file-specific minor modes using file variables: see the very bottom of [this documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), which will also mention hooks which is probably the way to go if you want to implement the logic you’ve described.

Comment: You add to `org-mode-hook` a function that checks the file for the tag and, if it finds it, enables the minor mode: `(defun check-tag-enable-minor-mode () (when  (check-tag "foo") (foo-minor-mode 1)))` and `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'check-tag-enable-minor-mode)`. You still have to write the `check-tag` function and fix what minor mode you want to enable.